# Is Pie an unknown dessert in Mexico/Spanish-speaking countries?

Tags: traducción, comida

In "Las Uvas de la Ira" ("The Grapes of Wrath", the English "piece of pie" is translated as "trozo de pastel."

My understanding is that "pastel" is cake, not pie. Is there really no Spanish word dedicated to pie, so that the word for cake must be used as a substitute?

Comment: In my experience in every Spanish speaking country I have been, they have different names for pie, cake ,etc..for example in Cuba we use `pie` de coco/guayaba and it's pronounce in the same way as English, pastel is different for us http://www.glotoncubano.com/imagenes/comida%20cubana/postres/PASTEL%20DE%20COCO%20A%20LA%20CUBANO.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Spanish we have two words: *pastel* and *tarta*. There is not an exact correspondence between the English words *pie* and *cake* and these two. For instance, an apple pie would be *tarta de manzana*, but a meat pie would be *pastel de carne*. So your translation might be correct or not depending on the kind of pie.

Answer (score -1):

The word for Pie is pay pronounced pie. And if the translation of that idiom is different well that's because it's an idiom.

Comment: a dessert is an idiom?

Comment: "piece of pie" is an idiom, isn't it? And if it's not, we are used to cake more than pie. For example "Pie chart" is "Diagrama de pastel"

Comment: @JaimeCruzTriana the idiom is "piece of cake". There is also "easy as pie" :)

Comment: But in this case (I didn't give enough context) it is talking about a literal piece of pie, not an idiomatic expression.

Comment: The point here is that we prefer "cake" instead of "pie" and I think that is because pies are "new" or not that spread [known by averyone but just as a dessert eaten not very often] in hispanic cuisine but not that normal as a cake.

Comment: [At least for Mexico, this answer is correct.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay) I've never heard of anyone call it a tarta or anything else.